# Initializing a const array inside a struct

Tags: c

```
#define LENGTH 6
typedef char data_t[LENGTH];
struct foo {
    const data_t data;
    ...
}
...
void bar(data_t data) {
    printf("%.6s\n", data);
    struct foo myfoo = {*data};
    printf("%.6s\n", foo.data);
}
```

I'm trying to have this struct which holds directly the data I'm interested in, `sizeof(foo) == 6+the rest`, not `sizeof(foo) == sizeof(void*)+the rest`. However I can't find a way to initialize a struct of type `foo` with a `data_t`. I think maybe I could remove the `const` modifier from the field and use `memcpy` but I like the extra safety and clarity.

I don't get any compile errors but when I run the code I get

```
123456
1??
```

so the copy didn't work properly I think.

This is for an arduino (or similar device) so I'm trying to keep it to very portable code.

Is it just not possible ?

EDIT: removing the `const` modifier on the `data_t` field doesn't seem to help.

Comment: The difficulty is that the argument `data_t data` is equivalent to `char *data`, and there isn't an easy way around that that I can think of at an hour and a half after bed-time.  C doesn't support direct array assignment, of course.  Can you pass a `struct foo *` to `bar`?  Then it's easy: `struct foo foo = *data;`.

Comment: Shouldn't the typedef be `typedef char data_t[LENGTH];`? And `struct foo = {*data};` doesn't look valid to me...

Comment: `struct foo f {.data = {data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5]} }`

Comment: Why would you need const data_t as opposed to const struct foo?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `{.data` is not portable, and what would you do if `#define LENGTH 6` ever changes to 6000?

Comment: @n.m. `.data` is C99, so that's pretty portable. Length=6 is the reason why I didn't care to write this in an answer.

Comment: Removing `const` wouldn't help, because you are initializing the first item of the array. You need to use `memcpy`.

Comment: I know this isn't quite what you're looking for, but you can declare `struct foo* foo = (struct foo*)data;` [like this](https://tio.run/##bY9PC4JAEMXv@ykGJdRQoX9eLG9Rh@jUrSK2Xc2F2hVdgxA/u@2qkVB7eAvzm3lvhng3QprGZJzcSxrDspCUCT@NkEnjhPEYduv95rCFAMlXFqsakBTnQLHEF3ns4DlEqJB5SSQkQkCFQD0ieCH7vvYLUa36noJRuOLc/uFOP5jljMvENkZ@UJy44XYwbNk3ZdxGrcAelJwu5q@J4l7UO9UIKQoPzLjdpQ7WUJ6VNbFcsKZaZlrmWhZaAqvWAfqAj1nTvAE)

Comment: There are other fields in the struct I'm actually using. also i'd like the data to be copied and be part of the struct to avoid having pointers inside the `foo` struct

Comment: @user2475269 you can't do that. Either the `data` member has to be a pointer, or `struct foo*` has to point to the memory that the `data` was located in prior, but you can't copy `data` to a new `struct foo` as a `const` within the declaration, that's impossible.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That cast would violate all kinds of strict aliasing rules.

Comment: `memcpy` is 100% clean and portable if you don't use the const qualifier. I you do keep const I think it's UB, but no existing compiler I know of will do anything unexpected.

Comment: @PSkocik `char*` doesn't apply to strict aliasing rules

Comment: @PatrickRoberts But they do apply to `struct foo` and `char[6]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this, for some cost `>=0`.

```
typedef struct
{
    char c[LENGTH];
} data_t; // this struct is freely copyable

struct foo
{
    const data_t data; // but this data member is not
    int what;
};

void foo (char* x) {
    data_t d;                         // declare freely copyable struct instance
    memcpy(d.c, x, sizeof(d.c));      // memcpy it
    struct foo foo = { d, 42 };       // initialise struct instance with const member
    ...
};
```

Some compilers (e.g. clang) are even able to optimise away the redundant copying (from `x` to `d.c` and then from `d` to `foo.data` ⇒ from `x` straight to `foo.data`). Others (gcc I'm looking at you) don't seem to be able to achieve this.

If you pass around pointers to `data_t` rather than straight `char` pointers, you won't need this additional memcpy step. OTOH in order to access the `char` array inside `foo` you need another level of member access (`.data.c` instead of just `.data`; this has no runtime cost though).

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do it in a standard compliant way.

Due to its being `const`, `const char data[6];` must be initialized to be usable, and it may only be initialized *statically* (static objects with no initializer get automatically zeroed), with a *string literal*, or with a *brace-enclosed initializer list*. You cannot initialize it with a pointer or another array.

If I were you, I would get rid of the `const`, document that `.data` shouldn't be changed post-initialization, and then use `memcpy` to initialize it.

(`const` on struct members doesn't work very well in my opinion. It effectively prevents you from being able to have initializer functions, and while C++ gets around the problem a little bit by having special language support for its constructor functions, the problem still remains if the `const` members are arrays).